# Nested html dl dt dd

Tags: html, semantics, markup

I want to check my thinking. I need to create HTML code for the UI design below and I have used nested `dl`s in my markup. Is this semantically valid? If not, how else should I implement this design in HTML?

[UI design](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/504792/ui-element.png)

```
<dl>
    <dt>Section one</dt>
    <dd>
        <dl>
            <dt>Sub-Section one</dt>
            <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis justo justo, aliquam vel imperdiet a, semper sed felis. Nunc nec odio non massa pellentesque blandit et in velit. Proin massa libero, pulvinar at consectetur ut, ullamcorper id ipsum. Mauris in lorem ligula. </dd>

            <dt>Sub-Section two</dt>
            <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis justo justo, aliquam vel imperdiet a, semper sed felis. Nunc nec odio non massa pellentesque blandit et in velit. Proin massa libero, pulvinar at consectetur ut, ullamcorper id ipsum. Mauris in lorem ligula. </dd>

            <dt>Sub-Section three</dt>
            <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis justo justo, aliquam vel imperdiet a, semper sed felis. Nunc nec odio non massa pellentesque blandit et in velit. Proin massa libero, pulvinar at consectetur ut, ullamcorper id ipsum. Mauris in lorem ligula. </dd>

            <dt>Sub-Section four</dt>
            <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis justo justo, aliquam vel imperdiet a, semper sed felis. Nunc nec odio non massa pellentesque blandit et in velit. Proin massa libero, pulvinar at consectetur ut, ullamcorper id ipsum. Mauris in lorem ligula. </dd>

            <dt>Sub-Section five</dt>
            <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis justo justo, aliquam vel imperdiet a, semper sed felis. Nunc nec odio non massa pellentesque blandit et in velit. Proin massa libero, pulvinar at consectetur ut, ullamcorper id ipsum. Mauris in lorem ligula. </dd>
        </dl>
    </dd>

    <dt>Section two</dt>
    <dd>etc..</dd>

    <dt>Section three</dt>
    <dd>etc..</dd>

    <dt>Section four</dt>
    <dd>etc..</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably have used nested unordered lists using h* tags for the section titles, but your DL use seems fine. People debate constantly about what is the proper use of DLs.

Comment: As long as some sort of list is used, it doesn't really matter IMO. Just don't use a table!